# is there a way to know if a directory on the sdcard has any images in it?

Tags: android, image, sd-card

obviously, I could just do a recursive search in the folder for images, but is there a faster way?

Comment: there is a method listFiles() that will give you all the file names in an array for the directory.No need any recursive call

Comment: supposed you have /sdcard, /sdcard/a, /sdcard/a/b, /sdcard/a/b/c/d/test.jpg.  the directory I want to see if has any images is "/sdcard/a" - I need to do this recurisvely.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/somedir");
if(f.isDirectory()) {
    ....
```

Might also want to check f.exists() because if it exists and isDirectory() returns false then you will have a problem. There is also isReadable()... have a look at the documentation: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html